# Issue with hover in CSS

Tags: html, css

Whenever i hover my mouse not on the text but on the other side of the text it shows my hover.. i want it so it hover only on the text itself not when my mouse is outside the text.
here is my code

```
<div class="MiniListAll">
  <ul>
    <li class="MiniListLI">  Christmas trees    </li>    
    <li class="MiniListLI">  Christmas lights   </li>  
    <li class="MiniListLI">   Ornaments         </li>   
    <li class="MiniListLI">  Tree toppers       </li>  
    <li class="MiniListLI">   Candle holders    </li>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.MiniListLI{
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #737373;

}
.MiniListLI:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: black;

}
```

i tried googling the answer but nothing came up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use inline elements inside `<li>` tags:

HTML

```
<div class="MiniListAll">
  <ul>
    <li class="MiniListLI"><a href="#">Christmass trees</a></li>
    <li class="MiniListLI"><a href="#">Christmass lights</a></li>
    <li class="MiniListLI"><a href="#">Ornaments</a></li>
    <li class="MiniListLI"><a href="#">Tree toppers</a></li>
    <li class="MiniListLI"><a href="#">Candle holders</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.MiniListLI {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.MiniListLI a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #737373;
}
.MiniListLI a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: black;
}
```

[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/c2f6oLyp/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

CSS:

```
.MiniListLI{
   list-style-type: none;
}

.MiniListLI a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #737373;
}

.MiniListLI a:hover{  
   text-decoration: underline;
   color: black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="MiniListAll">
  <ul>
     <li class="MiniListLI"><a href="#">Christmass trees</a></li>    
     <li class="MiniListLI"><a href="#">Christmass lights</a></li>  
     <li class="MiniListLI"><a href="#">Ornaments </a></li>   
     <li class="MiniListLI"><a href="#">Tree toppers </a></li>  
     <li class="MiniListLI"><a href="#">Candle holders </a></li>  
  </ul>
</div>
```